# How get size in pixels of Logo and Zoom in GoogleMap android API 2

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I create android project with GoogleMap API v.2. I need create my overlay over map between "Google"-logo and "Zoom"-icons - see my picture.

[image]

I know horizontal size of my Activity. For calculate horizontal size of my overlay I need also sizes of this "Logo" and "Zoom". How I know its horizontal and vertical sizes of "Logo" and "Zoom"?